# How do you check whether 2 conditions are true or false in an array?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

there,

I've been trying for several hours to make a loop to check if one of the first 2 elements of the array are true.

I would like to check if "a" or "b" of the array "arr_bool" is true and if it is then write the word "TEST" in the array "arr_string".

Basically, check 2 by 2 whether (a or b), (c or d), (e or f) are true or false.

Do you have an idea?

My last test is this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("TEST", overlay = true)

var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 3, 6, frame_width  = 1, border_width = 1, border_color = #696969)


a = false
b = true
c = false
d = true
e = false
f = true


arr_bool = array.from(a, b, c, d, e, f)
arr_string = array.new_string(0)


for i = 0 to array.size(arr_bool) - 1
    if(array.get(arr_bool, i) or array.get(arr_bool, i+1))
        array.push(arr_string, 'TEST')

if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to array.size(arr_string) - 1
        table.cell(tbl, 0, i, text = str.tostring(array.get(arr_string, i)), text_color = color.white, bgcolor = #696969)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the incremental step of the `for` loop with the `by` keyword. You just need to increase your step by 2.

Below code assumes the length of the array is an even number. If that is not guaranteed, you need to add an additional check.

```
//@version=5
indicator("TEST", overlay = true)

var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 3, 6, frame_width  = 1, border_width = 1, border_color = #696969)

a = false
b = false
c = false
d = true
e = true
f = false
g = true
h = true

arr_bool = array.from(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
string s = ""

len = array.size(arr_bool)

for k = 0 to len - 1 by 2
    _first = array.get(arr_bool, k)
    _second = array.get(arr_bool, k + 1)

    s := s + "[" + str.tostring(k) + "]: " + str.tostring(_first) + " OR "  + "[" + str.tostring(k + 1) + "]: " + str.tostring(_second) + " is: " + str.tostring(_first or _second) + "\n"

if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, high, s)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand better..
here [2] false OR [3] true is true, Why is it true because it is _first or _second?

Comment: The logic operation is  `or` as you asked for. That means, if one of the variables is `true`, the result will be `true`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made a mistake... I've been looking too hard and my brain is playing tricks on me...